# user IIS7 uses when identify impersonate= true and a specific user is not specified

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, web-config

If I have the following line in my web.config file...

```
<identity impersonate = "true" />
```

And the IIS7 site is set to use anonymous authentication

(Notice I am not specifying a specifc user in the web config)

What user will IIS7 use to service the request, and what effect will this have?  There is debate with my co-workers as to whether the user which is entered into the "Connect As" dialogue is used by IIS.

Comment: Are you running this website on localhost?

Comment: No, on a remote server using IIS7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it will not.  There is a separate section for that.  Here is a link that defines how you set the impersonation user.  [Link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730708%28WS.10%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the debate by showing this on a page, but I am pretty sure `Anonymous` is going to be the answer:

```
Response.Write(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your website setting System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name will return an empty string. In short all the users will be anonymous even if you have set impersonation=true